# How to convert string from JS string format in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, beanshell

I am newbie in Jmeter. I am able to capture the session id as `"result.sessionToken = 'A45833C7\x2D4535\x2D49C8\x2DBB46\x2D15819383F3BB';"` using **"Regular Expression Extractor"**. However, this session Token ID in request is going in different format **"A45833C7-4535-49C8-BB46-15819383F3BB"**. 
Can anyone tell me, how to convert the captured dynamic data from 1 format to other? We have "**Convert" attribute in "web_reg_save_param()**" function in Load runner, do we have such function in Jmeter?

OR

How can we write our own code to replace **"\x2D"** with **"-"**?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have `ID` variable with the value of `A45833C7\x2D4535\x2D49C8\x2DBB46\x2D15819383F3BB`

You can replace `\x2` with `-` Using [__javaScript()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) function as follows:

**Just replace**

```
${__javaScript("${ID}".split('\x2').join('-'),)}
```

**Replace and store result into `ID` variable**

```
${__javaScript("${ID}".split('\x2').join('-'),ID)}
```

**Replace and store result into `FOO` variable**

```
${__javaScript("${ID}".split('\x2').join('-'),FOO)}
```

For more information on using JMeter Functions see [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series

Comment: Thank you. ${__javaScript("${ID}".split('\x2').join('-'),ID)} function worked.

Comment: @Dmitri: Want to replace the string from "C:\Users\Desktop\test.properties" to "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.properties".  Have tried as you said in the answer. But didn't get what I expected. Tried syntax: ${__javaScript("c:\pest11.properties".split('\\').join('\\\\'),ID)}. Can you please help me out.